# Copy 10 rows by 10 rows within the same worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

My intention is to cut the 10 rows above (`Range("A1:A10")`) and move them to Range("C1"). Then, continue from `Range("A11:A20")` and paste them to `Range("C21")`. The loop will continue until the last cells in column A contains the data. However, by using the cut method, it shows error. The code shows below:

```
Sub RowsByRows()
    Dim rngCut As Range, rngPaste As Range
    Set rngCut = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")
    Set rngPaste = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1")
    Do While Application.CountA(rngCut) > 0
        rngCut.Cut Destination:=rngPaste
        Set rngCut = rngCut.Offset(10, 0)
        Set rngPaste = rngPaste.Offset(20, 0)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

See if this works for you,

```
Sub RowsByRows()
    Dim rws As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    x = 0
    y = 0

    For i = 1 To (rws / 10) + 1
        Range("A" & 1 + y & ":A" & 10 + y).Cut Destination:=Cells(1 + x, 3)
        x = x + 20
        y = y + 10
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Nicely done.. but you will have to amend it slightly :) If there are 21 rows of data, this code will ignore the data in the 21st row :)

Comment: Adding one more loop will fix that

Comment: ++ Yup that fixes it :)

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub RowsByRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, rw As Long, i As Long
    Dim StartRow As Long, EndRow As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To lRow Step 10
            StartRow = i: EndRow = StartRow + 9

            Range("A" & StartRow & ":A" & EndRow).Cut _
            Destination:=.Cells(1 + rw, 3)

            rw = rw + 20
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what I try to look for! Thanks a lot! :)